# Mosquitto with MQTTS and WSS in the same broker

Tags: ssl, mqtt, mosquitto

I am trying to set up a Mosquitto broker using secure connection.

I was able to configure and make it work correctly with MQTTS, I was able to test using my ESP32 and MQTTBox

Now I am trying to use a websocket to connect a web application but I believe that I am failing in some Mosquitto configuration.

For MQTTS I used "CA signed server certificate" and port 8083 and everything worked fine with MQTTBox and ESP32.

I spent the whole weekend researching and trying different configurations but I was unable to make the connection work in both ways. Can someone help me? Thanks!

```
# First of all, use this options on mosquitto.conf
per_listener_settings true
allow_anonymous false
password_file /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/pwfile.conf

# Rules for access topics
acl_file /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/aclfile.conf

# Now, use this options on mosquitto.conf
listener 8883
cafile /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key

listener 8083
websockets
cafile /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
```

**EDIT, this is the Mosquitto log:**

```
1621899173: mosquitto version 2.0.10 starting
1621899173: Config loaded from /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf.
1621899173: Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 8883.
1621899173: Opening ipv4 listen socket on port 8883.
1621899173: Opening websockets listen socket on port 8083.
1621899173: mosquitto version 2.0.10 running
1621899174: Sending CONNACK to ::ffff:192.168.15.2 (0, 5)
1621899174: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1621899176: Sending CONNACK to ::ffff:192.168.15.2 (0, 5)
1621899176: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
1621899177: Sending CONNACK to ::ffff:192.168.15.2 (0, 5)
1621899177: Client <unknown> closed its connection.
```

**EDIT, I used this commands to create the certificate:**

```
openssl genrsa -des3 -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt
openssl genrsa -out server.key 2048
openssl req -new -out server.csr -key server.key
openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 360
openssl x509 -in server.crt -sha1 -noout -fingerprint
```

[image: MQTTBox MQTTS connected]

[image: MQTTBox MQTTS config]

[image: MQTTBox WSS disconnected]

[image: MQTTBox WSS config]

Answer (score 2):

From the [mosquitto.conf](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html) man page

> **protocol** *value*
>
> Set the protocol to accept for the current listener. Can be mqtt, the default, or websockets if available.
>
> Websockets support is currently disabled by default at compile time. Certificate based TLS may be used with websockets, except that
> only the cafile, certfile, keyfile, ciphers, and ciphers_tls1.3
> options are supported.
>
> Not reloaded on reload signal.

Your Websockets listener should look like this;

```
listener 8083
protocol websockets
cafile /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /usr/local/etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
```

Comment: Sorry, I typed it wrong here on Stackoverflow. My configuration file was already with 'protocol websockets' as you said.

Comment: Then without at least some indication about what the actual error is it will be impossible to answer. "Connection Error" on it's own doesn't tell us anything useful. Update the question with the relevant log output from Mosquitto and the client you are using to test (The broker certificate will have to be signed by a public CA for WSS to work with a web browser)

Comment: Thank for your attention @hardillb. I updated the question with the log.

Comment: Run 

    `mosquitto -v -c /path/to/config/file.conf`

to see if there are any apparent errors.  

Sadly, you are not alone.  My own quest to find wss:// function has turned up the same frustrations, and the mosquitto documentation is quite poor..